# Is there analytics software that can reveal the company that is view your website?

Tags: web, google-analytics, analytics

I'm trying to find out if there is an analytics program that can reveal the company that is view your website? For example, not just reveal the demographics or location of people viewing your site, but their company name/info.

thanks

Comment: For example leady.com or leadlabs by wiredminds.de.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out the "Service Provider" report - might have some of what you're looking for.

Tom

Answer (score 1):

You've got to remember that one of the core aspects of the Google Analytics software is that you **cannot** collect personally-identifiable information, and in this case a company name whether it was deduced from IP, Geolocation or otherwise would absolutely be that type of information.

My advice would be if you *do* find this software/plugin/code snippet for GA then to completely ignore it as you don't want any personally-identifiable information in your profile as if Google find it you could lose all your data when and if they suspend your account.